# How do I make these 3 sections have a parallax scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

I am doing a uni project and I am rather new to all this so be gentle.

I have 3 sections - a CV section, a what I like section, and an image section. Although there are a header and footer too, which does not need to be included in the parallax.

I have tried both JS and CSS implementations/tutorials to try to use the parallax effect with with my own markup to no avail. Can anyone help me?

Below are the pages' html and css (I have tried to only include the relavent CSS.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text">



       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title >BGDR creative</title>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<!--<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>-->
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/lato:n1,i1,n3,i3,n4,i4,n7,i7,n9,i9:all.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
<div id="progressBar" data-0="width: 0%" data-end="width: 100%" ></div>
<div id="offset">10</div> 
<body id="about">
    <header>


  <!-- h1 is a text logo (i need to check to see having a h1 text logo is ok)-->

        <h1 id="logo" role="button"> 
            <a href="../../Dreamweaver /Pages/Home.html" title="Back to the front page" role="link">
                <span id="bgdr">
                    BGDR
                </span>
                    <br>
                <span id="creative">
                    creative
                </span>
            </a>
        </h1>


   <!-- navigation menu-->          
  <nav id="nav" role="navigation" align="right">

                <ul>
                <li><a href="Contact.html" title="Contact Me" rel="next">CONTACT        </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="Blog.html" title="A blog of my work and musings" rel="next">BLOG   </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="CV.html" title="CV" rel="next">CV                      </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="Visual.html" title="Film and Animation" rel="next">VISUAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sound.html" title="Sound" rel="next">SOUND                         </a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html" title="About BGDR" rel="next">ABOUT            </a>    </li>
                <li ><a href="Home.html" title="Go Home" rel="next">FRONT PAGE      </a>    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>  
                <br>


    <!--Below are the social netowrking buttons with <a> tags to link externally-->
       <section class="social" role="button" align="right">       
            <a href="https://twitter.com/sambegdouri" title="Tweet Me!" target="_blank">
                <img src="../../BGDR creative/Assests/Icons/twitter.svg"  alt="Twitter" width="40" height="40">
            </a>

            <a href="../../Dreamweaver /Pages/..." title="Facebook Page" target="_blank">
                <img src="../../BGDR creative/Assests/Icons/facebook.svg" name="Facebook" alt="Facebook" width="40" height="40">
            </a>

            <a href="https://instagram.com/sambegdouri/" title="My Insta Feed" target="_blank">
                <img src="../../BGDR creative/Assests/Icons/Insta2.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Instagram">
        </a><a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/sambegdouri" title="My Linkedin Profile" target="_blank"><img src="../../BGDR creative/Assests/Icons/linkedin.svg" height="40" width="40" alt="Linkedin"></a></section>

</header>
<div id="wholePage">
    <main role="main">
    <h2>CIRRICULUM VITAE</h2>
    <section role="contentinfo">


<div id="tableGroup">
<table id="workTable">
<tr class="skillsTabHeight">
<th colspan="2"><img src="../Assests/CV icons/work.svg" alt="Experience" width="10%" height="10%"></th>
</tr>
  <tr>  
<th colspan="2" ><h3 class="headerCell">EXPERIENCE</h3></th>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    Nulabug
    </td>
    <td>
    April 2015
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    Areia Creations
    </td>
    <td>
    2014 - April 2015
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    Animation Workshop
    </td>
    <td>
    Feburary 2013 - May 2013
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    SBS MTV
    </td>
    <td>
    April 2012
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

<table id="eduTable">

<tr class="skillsTabHeight">
<th colspan="2"><img src="../Assests/CV icons/Education.svg" alt="Education" width="80%" height="80%"></th>
</tr>


  <tr>  
<th colspan="2"><h3 class="headerCell">EDUCATION</h3></th>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    Bath Spa University
    </td>
    <td>
    October 2010 - Present
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    Bible College of Wales
    </td>
    <td>
    September 2008 - July 2009
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableAlign">
    <td>
    New College
    </td>
    <td>
    September 2006 - July 20108
    </td>
</tr>
</table>



<table id="otherTable">

<tr class="otherTableCenter">
    <th colspan="3"><h3 class="headerCell">Other Experience</h3></th>
</tr>

<tr class="otherTableCenter">
    <td>
    <img src="../Assests/CV icons/1Pencil.svg" alt="Teaching" height="80%" width="80%">
    </td>
    <td>
   <img  src="../Assests/CV icons/Dollarbag.svg" alt="Banking" height="80%" width="80%">
    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Chart.svg" alt="Sales" height="80%" width="80%">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="otherTableCenter">
    <td>
    Teaching
    </td>
    <td>
    Banking
    </td>
    <td>
    Sales
    </td>
</tr>

  <tr class="otherTableCenter">
    <td>
    <img src="../Assests/CV icons/cap.svg" alt="Youth" height="50%" width="50%">
    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Moviecam.svg" alt="Film" height="80%" width="80%">
    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Musickeyboard.svg" alt="Musician" height="80%" width="80%">
    </td>
</tr>

  <tr class="otherTableCenter">
    <td>
    Youth Work
    </td>
    <td>
    Film
    </td>
    <td>
    Musician
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>





<aside role="tablist">
<table id="skillsTable">
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><img src="../Assests/CV icons/spanner.svg" alt="Skills" height="90%" width="90%" class="centerIcon"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" >
<h3 class="headerCell">Skills</h3>
</th>
</tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>DAWs</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    </td>       
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Audition</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    </td>       
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>After Effects</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Premiere Pro</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
</td>    
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Illustrator</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    </td> 
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>HTML/CSS/JS</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    </td>       
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Edge/Muse</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
 </td>         

 </tr>
  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Cinema 4D</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
  </td> 
  </tr>

  <tr class="blankRow"></tr>

  <tr>
<th colspan="2"><img src="../Assests/CV icons/speech.svg" alt="Languages" width="10%" height="10%" class="centerIcon"></th>
</tr>

  <tr>  
<th colspan="2"><h3 class="headerCell">Languages</h3></th>
</tr>

<tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>English</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    </td>       
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>Français</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    </td>       
  </tr>

  <tr class="skillsTabHeight">
    <td>한국어</td>
    <td><div class="circleStroke"><span class="circleFill"></span></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    <div class="circleStroke"></div>
    </td>       
  </tr> 

</table>
</aside>

<aside>
<table id="profileTable">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<img src="../Assests/CV icons/face.svg" alt="me" width="20%" height="25%" class="centerIcon">
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<h3 class="headerCell">PROFILE</h3>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Currently working in Korea and am seeking employment in visual multimedia/UI.  I have multimedia (sound/(moving) image) experience professionally, and continue working on personal projects. I consider myself an  individual who has a friendly disposition; a type of guy who talks about new ideas. I delight in new cultures and practices. A proficient speaker of French and currently learning Korean.  I enjoy learning new creative software (see below) to make something cool. I like going out and taking photos. And my favourite music is liquid Drum and Bass. Lastly, I am an Oxford comma kind-of-guy.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</aside>


</div>
</section>

 <section role="contentinfo">
     <div id="sectionTwoScroll"
     data-bottom="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5)" 
        data--100-bottom="opacity:1; transform: scale(1)"


        data--100-top="opacity:0"
        data-top="opacity:1">

        <h2 class="scrollSectionText1" >

        My Wife &amp; I</h2>
     </div>
 <img src="../Assests/Pics/Somi and ME - Hanok.jpg" alt="Somi and I in a Hanok" id="samWifeImg">
 </section> 

 <section>
 <div id="sectionThreeScroll" > 
 <div data-bottom="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5)" 
        data--100-bottom="opacity:1; transform: scale(1)"


        data--50-top="opacity:0"
        data-top="opacity:1">
     <h2 class="scrollSectionText1">
     STUFF I LIKE
     </h2>
     </div>
     <div data-bottom="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5)" 
        data--100-bottom="opacity:1; transform: scale(1)"


        data--600-top="opacity:0"
        data-top="opacity:1">
  <table id="likeTable">

     <tr class="likeTableRow">

        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Coffeemaker.svg" alt="Coffee" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Compactcam.svg" alt="Photography" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Drums.svg" alt="Drum" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Moviescene.svg" alt="Film" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="likeTableRow">
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        COFFEE
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        PHOTOGRAPHY
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        DRUMS
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        FILMS
        </td>
     </tr>

    <tr class="blankRow"></tr>

     <tr class="likeTableRow">
        <td>
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/DJ.svg" alt="DJ" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Education.svg" alt="Learning" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Rainumbrella.svg" alt="Rain" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Teabag.svg" alt="Tea" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="likeTableRow">
        <td>
        MIXING
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        LEARNING
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        RAIN
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        TEA
        </td>
     </tr>


      <tr class="blankRow"></tr>


          <tr class="likeTableRow">
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Piano.svg" alt="Piano" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Musickeyboard.svg" alt="Midi Controler" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Speakers.svg" alt="Speaker" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        <img src="../Assests/CV icons/Browserscript.svg" alt="Web Development" height="100%" width="100%">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="likeTableRow" >
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        MUSIC (playing)
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        MUSIC (production)
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        SOUND
        </td>
        <td class="likeTableCol">
        WEB
        </td>
     </tr>

 </table>
  </div>   
 </div>
 </section> 


</main>


    <footer id="footerCV" role="contentinfo">


    <a href="https://twitter.com/sambegdouri" title="Tweet Me!" target="_blank"><img src="../Assests/Icons/twitter.svg" height="64" width="64" alt="Twitter"></a>

    <a href="..." title="Facebook Page" target="_blank"><img src="../Assests/Icons/facebook.svg" name="Facebook" alt="Facebook" height="64" width="64"></a>

    <a href="https://instagram.com/sambegdouri/" title="My Insta Feed" target="_blank"><img src="../Assests/Icons/Insta2.png" height="64" width="64" alt="Instagram"></a>

    <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/sambegdouri" title="My Linkedin Profile" target="_blank"><img src="../Assests/Icons/linkedin.svg" height="64" width="64" alt="Linkedin"></a>

    </footer>
 </div>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init({
        render: function(data) {
            //Log the current scroll position.
            //console.log(data.curTop);
            $("#offset").text(data.curTop);
        }
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {

    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: lato,  sans-serif;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    margin:0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: grey;*/
}

#offset {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index:9999;
}
#progressBar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 7px;
    width:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width:100%;
    z-index:20001;
}

header {
    /*background-color: hsla(359,70%,46%,1.00);*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    z-index: 20000;

}

            /*This h1 is in the header section and the h1 has an ID=logo and is in 2 sections, id=bgdr and id=creative.*/

h1 {
    /*background-color: orange;*/
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    top:0px;
}


#logo {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 4.em;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;


}

            /*#bgdr and #creative IDs are part of the h1 (#logo). They are in 2 IDs so that I can adjust the BGDR and creative text independantly*/

#bgdr {
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight:100;
}

#creative {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-weight:100;
}   

            /* the "a" selector is followed by "link, visited and hover" to animate the states of menu/text links throughout the page/site*/

a:link {
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1.00);
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:300;
}

a:visited {
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1.00);
}

a:hover {
    color: hsla(0,0%,72%,1.00);
}

a:active {
    font-weight: 800;
}


            /*the ul, li, and .nav control the top nav menu. The ul is the table, il are the cells. (front page, about, contact, etc.)*/

ul {
    /*background-color: blue;*/

    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:75px;
    right:30px;
    padding: 0em;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    float: right;
}

 li {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    margin-left: 3em;
}

            /*This is a class for my social buttons that are just below the menu (not large buttons at the bottom of the page*/
.social {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 11em;
    right: 30px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    top: 170px;
}

            /*h2=page name e.g. About h3=Sound/music/web h4=long version*/
h2, h3, h4  {
            text-align: center; 
}   

            /*h2 is the title of each page eg "ABOUT"*/

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    position: relative;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    top: -40px;
}

h2 #homeH2 {
    position:relative;
    top: 200px;
}


h4 {
    font-weight:300; 
    font-size:1.4em
}

h2+p {
    text-align:center;
} 

main {
    position: relative;
    top: 240px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -5em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

#footerCV {
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto 0;
    top: 2200px;
    clear:both;
    z-index:5000;
} 

.blankRow {
     height: 45px;
 }

 #likeTable {
     position:relative;
     top: 150px;
     width:80%;
     margin-left: 10%; 
 }

 .likeTableRow {
     margin:50px;
 }

.likeTableCol {
    width:200px;
}


 #tableGroup{
     position:fixed;
     display:block;
     top:200px;
     width:100%;
     margin:auto;

 }


 #skillsTable {
    position: absolute;
    table-layout:fixed;
    display: compact;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    top: 22%;
 }
 .skillsTabHeight {

    height:35px;

}

#workTable {
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: compact;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 25%;
    left: 30%;
}

#eduTable {
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: compact;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 214px;
    left: 30%;
}
#otherTable {
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: compact;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 385px;
    left: 30%;
}

#profileTable {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    left: 73%;
    max-width: 26%; 
}


 .tableAlign {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: central;        
 }

th .centerIcon{
display: block;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

  .headerCell {
line-height: 0px;
margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
 }

   /*.headerCell {
      position: inherit;
      vertical-align:top;
     height: 1px;
     text-height:1px;
     text-align: center; 
 }*/

 logoCol {
    float: right;
 }
 .circleFill {
    margin: -1px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: circleFill; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: circleFill;
    -o-animation: circleFill; /* Opera 12+ */
     animation: circleFill;
     animation-duration: 5s;
 }

 .circleStroke {
margin:2px;
float:left;
 background-color: rgba(204, 0, 102, 0);
 border: 3px solid #333;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circleFill {
    0% { opacity:0.0 ; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }

}


#mePic {
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    left: 0%;
    top:0%;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#samWifeImg {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    max-width:100%;
    top: 1255px;
}


/*This is a div that is a container for the stuff I like section*/
#sectionThreeScroll{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    height:750px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top: 650px;
    z-index:2000;
    background-color:white;
}
/*This is a div that is a container for the h2 of Me and my wife at a Hanokmal*/
#sectionTwoScroll{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left: 42%;
    text-align:center;
    top: 1600px;
    z-index:3000;
}

/*This is a h2 class  for the h2 text that says "My Wife & I" AND "STUFF I LIKE"*/
.scrollSectionText1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align:center;
    color: black ;
}


.centerIcon {
    position:inherit;
    display: block;
    right:50%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to any parallax javascript resource in your code?

There are different parallax plugins out there that create different types of parallax effects. Here's one that I like to use that I think is what you are looking for:
http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js

It's really easy to use. Just download the plugin and include it in your project. Make sure you reference it after your jquery include.

```
<script src="/path/to/parallax.js"></script>
```

Then add data-parallax="scroll" to the section you want to have a parallax effect on and specify an image with data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg".

You want to make sure that the image you use is larger (in height) than the section it will appear in, as it scrolls at a different rate to that of the page/document.

Comment: I took out all the js and css code that i used to scroll. It was getting rather messy. But I will try and look at what you suggest.